# How to create a CPU type in QEMU that is not available by default?

Tags: arm, qemu

When I try the `qemu-system-arm -machine virt -cpu cortex-a53` command on qemu, I get the `qemu-system-arm: unable to find CPU model 'cortex-a53'` error message. But I can run the same command with `qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -cpu cortex-a53`.

According to ARM official website, cortex-A53 and cortex-A72 support both AArch32 and AArch64(with ARMV8-A) but qemu-system-arm does not work properly with cortex-a53 and cortex-a72.

As far as I understand, in QEMU, the "qemu-system-arm" command is typically used for emulating 32-bit ARM systems (AArch32), while the "qemu-system-aarch64" command is used for emulating 64-bit ARM systems (AArch64). The Cortex-A53 and Cortex-A72 CPU models are part of the ARMv8-A architecture, which is 64-bit in QEMU by default. Also, the Cortex-A32 cpu model with 32-bit ARMV8-A is not currently available in QEMU.

My questions are;

- Is there any way to run both 32-bit and 64-bit ARMV8-A architecture supporting cpu models like Cortex-A53 or Cortex-A72 in qemu-system-arm (as aarch32)?
- How can I create a 32-bit ARMV8-A cpu model in QEMU?
- Do you have any other suggestion to run Cortex-A53/72 models as 32-bit (aarch32, ARMV8-A) in QEMU?

Comment: did you try the aarch64 qemu?  and or read up on if it  it is a proper emulation of the core?

Comment: Yes I tried but same result. Also, I created a sample project with aarch64 ARMV8-A architecture for testing purposes and ran it successfully with qemu-system-aarch64. The problem is that a project with aarch32 ARMV8-A architecture does not work with both qemu-system-aarch64 or qemu-system-arm.

Comment: as with any cortex-a53 or a72 you switch modes and run your aarch32 code.  you are saying that qemu-system-aarch64 is only a partial sim?

Comment: how do you run aarch32 on your cortex-a72 now?

Comment: Arm System emulator
QEMU can emulate both 32-bit and 64-bit Arm CPUs. Use the qemu-system-aarch64 executable to simulate a 64-bit Arm machine. You can use either qemu-system-arm or qemu-system-aarch64 to simulate a 32-bit Arm machine: in general, command lines that work for qemu-system-arm will behave the same when used with qemu-system-aarch64.

Comment: quick google search.  did you try this?

Comment: "how do you run aarch32 on your cortex-a72 now?", that is the problem! I could not run aarch32 on my cortex-a72 qemu machine. 

When I try to run aarch64 ARMV8-A executable file on qemu-system-arm, I got error like that "ERROR:../../qom/object.c:721:object_new_with_type: assertion failed: (type != NULL)
Bail out! ERROR:../../qom/object.c:721:object_new_with_type: assertion failed: (type != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)"

BUT, I am able to run the same executable on qemu-system-aarch64.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot run "ARMV8-A 32-bit" executable in QEMU. If my executable initially is "ARMV8-A 64-bit" or "ARMV7-A 32-bit", it's fine. But in other cases, error occurs. 

So theoretically, QEMU can emulate both 32-bit and 64-bit Arm CPU, you're right. But the problem is in the CPU architecture. Please answer the following two questions; 1) Can you run a program compiled according to ARMV8-A 32-bit architecture in QEMU? 2) Or can you emulate ARM Cortex-A32 CPU?

Comment: I did some research on this and found that the Cortex-A32 CPU has exactly the architecture I want. Because the Cortex-A32 has 32-bit ARMV8-A. I looked at the supported cpu list with the command "-cpu ?" in both qemu-system-arm and aarc64. Then guess what I realized; Cortex-A32 is not supported in neither qemu-system-arm nor aarc64.

Comment: How are you running on real hardware, for example a raspberry pi or one of the clones?  They support aarch32 and 64 on real hardware except for the one that nobody made that is 32 bit only.  what is wrong with the examples online?

Comment: what actual hardware do you have that you are trying to figure things out on/for? and why are you not using that?

Comment: Real hardware is; quite expensive, only one person can debug at a time, it is multicore and has different operating systems etc... I could list more reasons for using emulators but I am sure you already know that. The "Why" part is unfortunately not open for discussion, we have to deal with the "How" part.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the problem. The problem is running the ARMV8-A 32-bit executable in QEMU. Or the other way around, how do I convert an ARMV8-A 32-bit elf file to ARMV8-A 64-bit? Or, how can I emulate the Cortex-A32 cpu in QEMU? If we can find an answer to one of these questions, I think the way forward will be clear.